# Why dofactory declare _true_ and _false_ variables

Tags: javascript, jquery

dofactory have javascript patterns and practices framework. And [here](http://dofactory.com/products/javascript-jquery-design-pattern-framework) ( 4th example in Idioms and Hacks ) they provide and example of a guru programmer code. Its all clear for me, except for one thing: why do they declare *true* and *false* variables? I mean this code:

`var _true_ = true; var _false_ = false;`

The only idea I have is they want to reduce the lookup time as done for undefined, which makes sure undefined was not overriden and reduce the lookup time. But it seems *true* and *false* doesnt give anything to performance.

Comment: a wild guess - these symbols are shortened to one character when code is minified.

Comment: Minifiers can also replace `true` and `false` with `!0` and `!1` respectively. The way the article collates "idioms" and "hacks" makes me think the end result is far less professional than they want it to be.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, `Minifiers can also replace true and false with !0 and !1`, it won't. Because `true === 1` is a fail. Most probably these symbols are used for minification.

Comment: @zerkms agreed with Frédéric Hamidi on !0 and !1. So still doesnt make much sense. Also angularjs and jquery doesnt have this kind of enhancements. And jquery has !0 and !1 in min version.

Comment: @NK !0 ===1 is also fail. Can you explain in more details why !0 substitution is not appropriate?

Comment: @NK, `true === 1` is the wrong test. `true === !0` passes as expected, as does `false === !1`.

Comment: ! operator always produces a boolean type. The values `null`, `undefined`, `0` etc are just acting as a `false` value not actually they are.

Comment: @NK how is it connected to the fact that minifiers substitute true and false to !0 and !1? You can have a look at it in jquery minified sources, so it can be done and it is done.

Comment: @YaroslavYakovlev, you're right